# Gravity Forms - Prevent Multiple Form Entries Same User ID

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

We are using Gravity Forms and need to prevent the user from accessing the form again after submission. This is the code we're using in the 'application.php' template:

```
    <?php
    if (get_current_user_id()) {
        //lookup current application:
        $query = "SELECT * FROM dg_application where user_id = " . get_current_user_id();
        $dg_application = $wpdb->get_row( $query, ARRAY_A );
        if ($dg_application["user_id"] && $dg_application["status"] == "Completed") {
            // custom field
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "form_complete_message", true);

        } else {
            //let Gravity Forms/WP do thier jobs
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                // Include the page content template.
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // End of the loop.
            endwhile;
        }

    } else {
        echo "Sorry. You must be logged in to view this form.";
    }

    ?>

</main><!-- .site-main -->

<?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>
```

But it's not working and not displaying the message like it should. The database name is correct. We are using a custom database. Any ideas why it might not be showing?

Comment: Doesn't help with your code but if you're just looking for a solution, I have a plugin that will help: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-submissions/

Comment: Thanks David! We actually already have that plugin... let me see if that will work.

Comment: Make sure you have GF 2.3 installed: https://www.gravityforms.com/my-account/downloads/

Comment: Hi David. Installed, enabled, but not working. We are using GF 2.2.5, but I don't see this being a requirement with the plugin. Could it be because we are using a custom table?

Comment: You'll definitely need GF 2.3. I'd start there and if you're still having issues, contact support: http://gravitywiz.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many ways. not sure this is the better way or not but it's working well for me.
This code will prevent form access for the current user if they already filled the form.

```
add_filter( 'gform_get_form_filter_3', 'custom_schedule', 10, 2 );
function custom_schedule( $form_string, $form ) {
    

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $search_criteria = array(
        'status'        => 'active',
        'field_filters' => array( //which fields to search
            array(
                'key' => 'created_by', 'value' => $current_user->ID, //Current logged in user
            )
        )
    );
    $form_id = 3;
    $entry = GFAPI::get_entries($form_id,$search_criteria);

    if ( !empty($entry) ) {
        $form_string = '<p>Sorry, you have reached the submission limit for this form.</p>';
    }   
    return $form_string;
}
```